# Web.xml data getting deleted Automatically from eclipse Mars Project folder

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Mars and working on my Semester J2EE Project , Many times when i start eclipse the WEB.XML get empty and a null pointer error is shown,And only this shows :

```
<xml>...
```

Fortunately i saved all XML entries into a different notepad file and i copy paste all from there, But it's happening only with that project not with other's, it's almost 3 month i am working on the application so can't delete or modify it ... 
Please help if someone having the Same Problem ...